installing V2ray or nekoray
I'm facing a problem after installing v2ray and nekoray on my system. Once the installation is complete an unexpected issue arises. When I click on Home, instead of opening the usual file manager and showing my folders like Downloads, Documents, etc., it opens a colorful app labeled Disk Usage Analyzer. My folders no longer open properly.
I thought a restart might fix the issue, but after rebooting I encountered the following errors:
[FAILED] Failed to start plymouth-quit.service Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.
[FAILED] Failed to start gpu-manager.service Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[FAILED] Failed to start gdm.service GNOME Display Manager.
[FAILED] Failed to start plymouth-quit.service Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen.

The system becomes unusable at this point, and I have no choice but to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I downloaded the v2rayng from the following website that belongs to GitHub: github.com/2dust/v2rayN/releases
Then I did the following:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install fuse libpcre2-16-0 libdouble-conversion3

To install nekoray I did the following:

I downloaded nekoray-4.0-beta3-2024-07-13-linux-x64.AppImage from GitHub, from https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray/releases

chmod +x nekoray-4.0-beta3-2024-07-13-linux-x64.AppImage

./nekoray-4.0-beta3-2024-07-13-linux-x64.AppImage –


After much effort, I finally realized that the issues were caused by the .appimage files. I downloaded and installed the Nekoray .deb file without any problems. However, when I add my VPN service, it doesn’t work. I believe there may be compatibility problems with Ubuntu 24.04. I’m considering installing the previous version.

Did you download nekoray-4.0-beta3-2024-07-13-linux-x64.AppImage from https://github.com/xf22001/nekoray/releases ? The Unicode ndash character at the end of step 3 looks like it doesn't belong there at the end of the command, and it might generate an error message if you tried to run it.

I downloaded it from https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray/releases. what is the difference between these two links?

The link in my last comment also provides a nekoray .deb file for users of Debian-based systems like Ubuntu who prefer to install a nekoray .deb file.

Thanks. I downloaded and installed the Nekoray .deb file without any issues. However, when I add my VPN service, it doesn’t work. I believe there may be compatibility problems with Ubuntu 24.04. I’m considering installing the previous version of Ubuntu.

Maybe try testing Ubuntu 22.04 in a virtual machine application like VirtualBox first before installing it in a physical machine.

I am considering that this issue might be hardware-related (e.g., storage, graphics, CPU, etc.), but I'm unsure. Could hardware be causing this behavior, or is it more likely a software/configuration issue? (RAM: 16 GB, CPU: Intel Core i5, 4th generation )

It's more likely to be a software/configuration issue. I'm using a free VPN in Ubuntu, the VPN that is built-in in the Opera web browser snap package. It is pre-configured to work right out of the box.
